# MOQ what happen if method setup intersect?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

What happen when two setup intersect or overlap if you prefer.

For example, in the below scenario the setup overlap because obviously `"aSpecificString"` is also considered as any string.

```
Interface ISomeInterface
{
    int SomeMethod(string param);
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeClass_ShouldBehaveProperly_GivenSomeScenario()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
        .Returns(100);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(0);

    /*the rest of the test*/
}
```

I wonder what happen when it intersect.

Does it throw an exception or does it fail to detect the overlap and use the first matching setup in the order they were added?

I think it's best to avoid overlapping setup.

Comment: according to documentation. The last call wins and nullifies previous calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation found online, The last call wins and nullifies previous calls.

So even in your case if the test was to call

```
SomeMethod("aSpecificString")
```

it would return `0` based on the setup in your example.

Comment: I did some testing and it is indeed what it does. When given an overlapping value, the last overlapping setup made is the one used.

Comment: Is it actual for the example from the question only? I am interested in the case when setups from the example are in reverse order. I want to setup throwing an exception for all cases except one. Will it work when I setup Throws for Any and Returns some value for the specified case after it?

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko I am not entirely sure what you are asking, Can you post a question with what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341367/moq-setups-overlapping-what-will-be-if-setup-any-case-and-concrete-after-it. It more easy to check than describe the question, but it will be a good contribution to the SO questions list, and maybe it helps somebody in the future.

Comment: I know that I can solve this problem with a delegate. But the scenario described in the question is more useful for the situation when we want to have some generic setup in "test initialize" method and overlap some concrete case in some concrete test method (possibly another case in another method too). Anyway, I think it is better to discuss it in the comments on the new question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't go down the path that you are going. I only see reams and reams of pain.  Instead, make your `Return` conditional:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string parameter) => parameter == "aSpecificString" ? 100 : 0);
```

I hope I managed to reach you before you started putting down significant code...

Comment: up-voted for showing the conditional return. (and the warning about the path. lol )

Comment: Interesting, the reason I went there was due to the nature of the interface I mocked. It's a formula engine interface and the mocked method is "evaluate". It's appeared more natural to me to do a setup per formula, but you are right, I could have done a "switch case" in the return instead for the 3 or 4 possible formula.

Comment: Although, in some test, I did specific setup for combination of formula and its arguments. This allowed me to care about a specific scenario. This ensure that if any other scenario happen, the test fail because it is not what was expected. Also, because there is multiple argument, the switch would have to be turned into "if{} else if{} else if{} else{throw} " statement. This would be messy for this case and I would need to explicitly throw in else case for unexpected arguments.

Comment: In the question the formula arguments were stripped because they were irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @AXMIM: I'm more of a "composition over inheritance" kinda guy, so I have to ask this: could you decompose your solution yet more? The natural side effect will be simpler tests that compose together with significantly less complexity. Of course, this is what all of us SRP fanatics keep preaching...