# Moq setups overlapping. What will be if setup any case and concrete after it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to setup the return value for the call with any arguments except one specified case, and another return value for this one case. Does the following code provide expected behavior? Does the test pass? And is it guaranteed for other possible situation that follows the described structure?

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    int SomeMethod(string param);
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeClass_ShouldBehaveProperly_GivenSomeScenario()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(1);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
        .Returns(100);

    Assert.AreEquel(100, mock.Object.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"));
    Assert.AreEquel(1, mock.Object.SomeMethod("anyString"));
}
```

And how about mixed setups, for example when we setup 'throws exception' for any argument, but 'returns value' for some specified?

```
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Throws<Exception>();
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
    .Returns(100);
```

What behavior is expected from the setup provided in the last code example?

---

From the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276400/moq-what-happen-if-method-setup-intersect/39277807?noredirect=1#comment106738963_39277807) I know that

> The last call wins and nullifies previous calls

But, do we have the same behavior when setups are in reverse order?

Comment: I'll do a little more digging for the exception. let me test this

Comment: I just tested your last code example and it passes

Comment: Ok re tested this and whether loose or strict, the behavior appears to be that loose matches need to go before specific matches to get the behavior you described.

Comment: Did you test the case with Throw too? I see one dangerous point in the example (I just copied it) we can have **0** because of default value not because of setup. I will change it to **1**.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko thinks about the setup as a stack, the last one will be first in the line for matching. If there is a match moq stops checking after it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, do we have the same behavior when setups are in reverse order?

**No** (Not in this case)

After testing it, it appears that when more specific expectations are done after the more loose matches the behavior is as expected

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeClass_ShouldBehaveProperly_GivenSomeScenario() {
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>(); // Works for Strict or Loose
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
        .Returns(100);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("anotherString"))
        .Returns(1);

    Assert.AreEqual(100, mock.Object.SomeMethod("aSpecificString")); //PASS
    Assert.AreEqual(1, mock.Object.SomeMethod("anotherString")); //PASS
    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
        mock.Object.SomeMethod("anyString")); //PASS
}
```

If however, the same expectations are done multiple times, the last one wins

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeClass_ShouldBehaveProperly_GivenSomeScenario2() {
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
       .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
        .Returns(100);
    mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("aSpecificString"))
        .Returns(1);

    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
        mock.Object.SomeMethod("anyString")); //PASS
    Assert.AreEqual(100, mock.Object.SomeMethod("aSpecificString")); //Fail
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is great. But it will be good to have some documented stuff because I see so many possible cases (also it is interesting how it works with conditional setups) and some of them can surprise once time. I tried to find it here https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart but it is missing. I will continue the research. Possibly it is an undocumented feature and isn't supported in all versions of Moq, and we have no guarantees that it will be supported in the future.

Comment: It looks like setups overlapping works anyway (I don't know about conditional setups with lambda). If we setup the case for any and for "some" after it, the last setup overlaps only "some". If we setup case for "some" and after that for any, the last one overlaps any.